# Setting whole array of chars to a value

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say we have:
`char someArray[4];` filled with {'a','b','c','d'}
And I want to set all 4 entries to 'f' or any other char really.
Instead of doing individually `someArray[0] = 'f'` (...) is there a way to set them all to a value?

Comment: Just a note: someArray without a zero byte is not a string. When I want an array of bytes that are not a string, to differentiate from strings I use `unsigned char[]` (or `signed char[]`) rather than `char []`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only because this an array of chars you can use [`memset`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memset.html):

```
memset(someArray, 'f', sizeof(someArray));
```

If you had an array of something else (say `int`) this method will not necessarily work for you as it sets the specified number of bytes (for a char array this is equivalent to the size of the array) to the 2nd parameter's value.  Thus if you try to do this with an `int` array and use a non-zero value `memset` will not assign that non-zero value to all `int`s in the array, but rather *every* byte for the number of bytes specified.

Comment: I like the use of sizeof, I'll mark this one as answer. Thanks everyone though.

Comment: the parenthesis around `someArray` are redundant: `sizeof someArray` is perfectly valid :-)

Comment: @pmg, noted, I prefer the "look" with parens. =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard library function memset. E.g.

```
memset(someArray, 'f', 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

man [`memset(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

```
char someArray[4];
memset(someArray, 'f', sizeof (someArray));
```